# How to connect Jquery slider with a dropdown box that is connected to a hidden div

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slider

I have combined a jquery slider, with a dropdown-box, with the function that a div will be displayed when a value is changed in either the slider or the dropdown-box.

However, the div becomes visible only when i change the value in the dropdown-box, not in the slider.

[Click here for jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tobbecokta/Uum8j/1/)

```
$(function() {
$('#range-start').change(function() {
    $('.colors').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
});

 function checkvalue(val) {
if (val === "others") document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'block';
else document.getElementById('color').style.display = 'none';
 }


 $(window).load(function() {
jQuery.fn.selectToUISlider = function(settings) {
    var selects = jQuery(this);

    //accessible slider options
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        labels: 3,
        //number of visible labels
        tooltip: true,
        //show tooltips, boolean
        tooltipSrc: 'text',
        //accepts 'value' as well
        labelSrc: 'value',
        //accepts 'value' as well    ,
        sliderOptions: null
    }, settings);


    //handle ID attrs - selects each need IDs for handles to find them
    var handleIds = (function() {
        var tempArr = [];
        selects.each(function() {
            tempArr.push('handle_' + jQuery(this).attr('id'));
        });
        return tempArr;
    })();

    //array of all option elements in select element (ignores optgroups)
    var selectOptions = (function() {
        var opts = [];
        selects.eq(0).find('option').each(function() {
            opts.push({
                value: jQuery(this).attr('value'),
                text: jQuery(this).text()
            });
        });
        return opts;
    })();

    //array of opt groups if present
    var groups = (function() {
        if (selects.eq(0).find('optgroup').size() > 0) {
            var groupedData = [];
            selects.eq(0).find('optgroup').each(function(i) {
                groupedData[i] = {};
                groupedData[i].label = jQuery(this).attr('label');
                groupedData[i].options = [];
                jQuery(this).find('option').each(function() {
                    groupedData[i].options.push({
                        text: jQuery(this).text(),
                        value: jQuery(this).attr('value')
                    });
                });
            });
            return groupedData;
        }
        else return null;
    })();

    //check if obj is array

    function isArray(obj) {
        return obj.constructor == Array;
    }
    //return tooltip text from option index

    function ttText(optIndex) {
        return (options.tooltipSrc == 'text') ? selectOptions[optIndex].text : selectOptions[optIndex].value;
    }

    //plugin-generated slider options (can be overridden)
    var sliderOptions = {
        step: 1,
        min: 0,
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        max: selectOptions.length - 1,
        range: selects.length > 1,
        //multiple select elements = true
        slide: function(e, ui) { //slide function
            var thisHandle = jQuery(ui.handle);
            //handle feedback 
            var textval = ttText(ui.value);
            thisHandle.attr('aria-valuetext', textval).attr('aria-valuenow', ui.value).find('.ui-slider-tooltip .ttContent').text(textval);

            //control original select menu
            var currSelect = jQuery('#' + thisHandle.attr('id').split('handle_')[1]);
            currSelect.find('option').eq(ui.value).attr('selected', 'selected');
        },
        values: (function() {
            var values = [];
            selects.each(function() {
                values.push(jQuery(this).get(0).selectedIndex);
            });
            return values;
        })()
    };

    //slider options from settings
    options.sliderOptions = (settings) ? jQuery.extend(sliderOptions, settings.sliderOptions) : sliderOptions;

    //select element change event    
    selects.bind('change keyup click', function() {
        var thisIndex = jQuery(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
        var thisHandle = jQuery('#handle_' + jQuery(this).attr('id'));
        var handleIndex = thisHandle.data('handleNum');
        thisHandle.parents('.ui-slider:eq(0)').slider("values", handleIndex, thisIndex);
    });


    //create slider component div
    var sliderComponent = jQuery('<div></div>');

    //CREATE HANDLES
    selects.each(function(i) {
        var hidett = '';

        //associate label for ARIA
        var thisLabel = jQuery('label[for=' + jQuery(this).attr('id') + ']');
        //labelled by aria doesn't seem to work on slider handle. Using title attr as backup
        var labelText = (thisLabel.size() > 0) ? 'Slider control for ' + thisLabel.text() + '' : '';
        var thisLabelId = thisLabel.attr('id') || thisLabel.attr('id', 'label_' + handleIds[i]).attr('id');


        if (options.tooltip == false) {
            hidett = ' style="display: none;"';
        }
        jQuery('<a ' + 'href="#" tabindex="0" ' + 'id="' + handleIds[i] + '" ' + 'class="ui-slider-handle" ' + 'role="slider" ' + 'aria-labelledby="' + thisLabelId + '" ' + 'aria-valuemin="' + options.sliderOptions.min + '" ' + 'aria-valuemax="' + options.sliderOptions.max + '" ' + 'aria-valuenow="' + options.sliderOptions.values[i] + '" ' + 'aria-valuetext="' + ttText(options.sliderOptions.values[i]) + '" ' + '><span class="screenReaderContext">' + labelText + '</span>' + '<span class="ui-slider-tooltip ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"' + hidett + '><span class="ttContent"></span>' + '<span class="ui-tooltip-pointer-down ui-widget-content"><span class="ui-tooltip-pointer-down-inner"></span></span>' + '</span></a>').data('handleNum', i).appendTo(sliderComponent);
    });

    //CREATE SCALE AND TICS
    //write dl if there are optgroups
    if (groups) {
        var inc = 0;
        var scale = sliderComponent.append('<dl class="ui-slider-scale ui-helper-reset" role="presentation"></dl>').find('.ui-slider-scale:eq(0)');
        jQuery(groups).each(function(h) {
            scale.append('<dt style="width: ' + (100 / groups.length).toFixed(2) + '%' + '; left:' + (h / (groups.length - 1) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%' + '"><span>' + this.label + '</span></dt>'); //class name becomes camelCased label
            var groupOpts = this.options;
            jQuery(this.options).each(function(i) {
                var style = (inc == selectOptions.length - 1 || inc == 0) ? 'style="display: none;"' : '';
                var labelText = (options.labelSrc == 'text') ? groupOpts[i].text : groupOpts[i].value;
                scale.append('<dd style="left:' + leftVal(inc) + '"><span class="ui-slider-label">' + labelText + '</span><span class="ui-slider-tic ui-widget-content"' + style + '></span></dd>');
                inc++;
            });
        });
    }
    //write ol
    else {
        var scale = sliderComponent.append('<ol class="ui-slider-scale ui-helper-reset" role="presentation"></ol>').find('.ui-slider-scale:eq(0)');
        jQuery(selectOptions).each(function(i) {
            var style = (i == selectOptions.length - 1 || i == 0) ? 'style="display: none;"' : '';
            var labelText = (options.labelSrc == 'text') ? this.text : this.value;
            scale.append('<li style="left:' + leftVal(i) + '"><span class="ui-slider-label">' + labelText + '</span><span class="ui-slider-tic ui-widget-content"' + style + '></span></li>');
        });
    }

    function leftVal(i) {
        return (i / (selectOptions.length - 1) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';

    }




    //show and hide labels depending on labels pref
    //show the last one if there are more than 1 specified
    if (options.labels > 1) sliderComponent.find('.ui-slider-scale li:last span.ui-slider-label, .ui-slider-scale dd:last span.ui-slider-label').addClass('ui-slider-label-show');

    //set increment
    var increm = Math.max(1, Math.round(selectOptions.length / options.labels));
    //show em based on inc
    for (var j = 0; j < selectOptions.length; j += increm) {
        if ((selectOptions.length - j) > increm) { //don't show if it's too close to the end label
            sliderComponent.find('.ui-slider-scale li:eq(' + j + ') span.ui-slider-label, .ui-slider-scale dd:eq(' + j + ') span.ui-slider-label').addClass('ui-slider-label-show');
        }
    }

    //style the dt's
    sliderComponent.find('.ui-slider-scale dt').each(function(i) {
        jQuery(this).css({
            'left': ((100 / (groups.length)) * i).toFixed(2) + '%'
        });
    });


    //inject and return 
    sliderComponent.insertAfter(jQuery(this).eq(this.length - 1)).slider(options.sliderOptions).attr('role', 'application').find('.ui-slider-label').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).css('marginLeft', -jQuery(this).width() / 2);
    });

    //update tooltip arrow inner color
    sliderComponent.find('.ui-tooltip-pointer-down-inner').each(function() {
        var bWidth = jQuery('.ui-tooltip-pointer-down-inner').css('borderTopWidth');
        var bColor = jQuery(this).parents('.ui-slider-tooltip').css('backgroundColor')
        jQuery(this).css('border-top', bWidth + ' solid ' + bColor);
    });

    var values = sliderComponent.slider('values');

    if (isArray(values)) {
        jQuery(values).each(function(i) {
            sliderComponent.find('.ui-slider-tooltip .ttContent').eq(i).text(ttText(this));
        });
    }
    else {
        sliderComponent.find('.ui-slider-tooltip .ttContent').eq(0).text(ttText(values));
    }

    return this;
}

$range = $('.range');
var $rangeSelect = $range.find('select');

$rangeSelect.selectToUISlider({
    labels: 12,
    sliderOptions: {
        orientation: 'vertical'
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {}
});


$range.find('.ui-slider').wrap('<div class="ui-slider-wrapper"></div>');

}); //]]>
```

Comment: People should comment more instead of downvoting. Starting the SO career with a downvoted question is a little rough, but yeah, next time if you can provide the fiddle when you post the question and maybe simplify it a bit (making a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)), those downvotes will turn into upvotes. `=]` +1 from me because it isn't THAT bad of a first question imo.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté *"Starting the SO career"* - you mean *StackOverflow account*, or *StackOverflow profile* right? Because unless OP actually works for stackexchange, he doesn't really have a  SO career ;)

Comment: @TJ Correct, I meant a Stack Overflow profile. I guess I didn't use to put much effort into my wording four years ago, but I have been constantly working on it in these last few years. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `slide` handler to trigger the `#range-start`'s `change` handler after you change its selected option:

```
//control original select menu
var currSelect = jQuery('#' + thisHandle.attr('id').split('handle_')[1]);
currSelect.find('option').eq(ui.value).attr('selected', 'selected');
//triggers the #range-start's change handler:
currSelect.trigger('change');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/Uum8j/5/)

[`.trigger()` Reference](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)